# How can we configure mail in Chronos?

Tags: mesos, email, mesos-chronos

I have setup one job on chronos server where I need to configure mail service.

The mail service will send job status for both the situation job failure and success.

Where and which file do I need to edit or add?

Answer (score 3):

You need to configure [following args](https://mesos.github.io/chronos/docs/configuration.html)

```
--mail_from  <arg>                 Mail from field
--mail_password  <arg>             Mail password (for auth)
-m, --mail_server  <arg>           Address of the mailserver in server:port format
--mail_ssl                         Mail SSL
--mail_user  <arg>                 Mail user (for auth)
```

An email will be sent to owner (or owners if they were provided in a comma, separated form see: [`sendNotification()`](https://github.com/mesos/chronos/blob/7a30e404e4eb627e358202867c76979b5f2c7708/src/main/scala/org/apache/mesos/chronos/notification/JobNotificationObserver.scala#L31-L35) and only for following occasion:

- [`JobRemoved`](https://github.com/mesos/chronos/blob/7a30e404e4eb627e358202867c76979b5f2c7708/src/main/scala/org/apache/mesos/chronos/notification/JobNotificationObserver.scala#L16)
- [`JobDisabled`](https://github.com/mesos/chronos/blob/e59943df6146ee870e46991b2acd448d77223697/src/main/scala/org/apache/mesos/chronos/scheduler/jobs/JobsObserver.scala#L21)
- [`JobRetriesExhausted`](https://github.com/mesos/chronos/blob/e59943df6146ee870e46991b2acd448d77223697/src/main/scala/org/apache/mesos/chronos/scheduler/jobs/JobsObserver.scala#L23)

To get information about the success you need to add this case.